# Why does the same code (Sheets.Add) exhibit two different behaviours?

Tags: excel, vba

Earlier this morning I asked my first question. Whilst investigating the suggestion put forward by Marco, I encountered a "does not make sense" situation. I went back to the immediately previous version of the macro suite to see what behaviour that gave. Let's call these Suite A and Suite B

In both Suite A and B there is the following code:

```
Public wsTemp As Worksheet  
Sub DrillDown()
```

In Suite A there is the following:

```
Sub HandleNewFileNumber()  
    If iK <> 0 Then  
        wbTgt.Close  
    End If  
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1))
```

In Suite B there is:

```
Sub HandleNewFileNumber()  
    If iK <> 0 Then  
        wbTgt.Close  
    End If  
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1))
```

No, I have not simply copied the same code twice. I took each piece of code out of the two separate workbooks. The code is identical.

When I run the macro suite A everything runs through to successful completion. When I run macro suite B I get Error 1004. In both cases the Set of wsTemp is the first time wsTemp has been referenced.

I am at a loss to understand how the same code can give two radically different results.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
```

Or

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(1))
End With
```

It's a very common problem: When you access an object from Excel (Sheet, Range, ...) and don't specify where it belongs to (eg a Worksheet belongs to a Workbook, a Range belongs to a Worksheet), VBA assumes you are referring to whatever is currently *active* (currently having the input focus).
If you write `Worksheets(1)`, Excel will translate this to *the first worksheet of the current active Workbook*. When `ThisWorkbook` is not the active workbook, this will lead to the situation that you ask Excel to add a sheet to one workbook but put it after the sheet of another workbook - and that's not possible and will throw an error.

VBA beginners will often try to solve this by put `activate`-statements in the code, but that's the wrong attempt. There is no need to activate anything. Instead, just tell VBA exactly what you want. By writing `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`, you specify that you mean the first sheet of `ThisWorkbook` (which is the WB where the code lives in). The second piece of code (using `With`) is just another way of writing it - but note that `.Worksheet` has a leading `.` that signals that we are accessing the sheet of the Workbook specified in the `With`-clause.

As a rule of thumb, **never** put anything in your code that let's VBA guess something.

Comment: I understand your point about telling VBA exactly what I want it to do. I will carry out a review of the entire suite of macros to try and spot other instances.I tried your suggestion and it still gave Error 1004. I also tried using ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count in the After clause and got 1004 again

Comment: @Peterthehistorian That should not be happening. Do you have anything fancy on those sheets, auto refreshing queries, event handlers?

Comment: @Peterthehistorian, check the comment by JvdV which gives you a Microsoft link describing said problem.

Comment: @GSerg No, nothing other than relatively basic things: For and Do loops, If Then Else End If, a little bit of With. The input, output and target workbooks are simple tabular worksheets. These get Workbook Open, SaveAs and Close. New sheets are added with Sheet Add.

Comment: @AAA I did read JvdV's link article. The scenario was different. The code example implied that more than 270 worksheets were being added. I was getting the error trying to add the second sheet to ThisWorkbook

Comment: @Peterthehistorian Another issue you should be considering is the use of `.Sheets` collection. This is a collection of all `worksheets` **and** `chart sheets`. You are telling VBA to add a new sheet after the `worksheets(1)`. What if there are no worksheets though in the workbook and there are only chart sheets? It's probably not your case, but you should consider it nonetheless.

Comment: @Peterthehistorian, it doesn't necessarily mean you have to add 270 sheets. The article indicates this problem can occur and may do at any time. Why not save after adding the first sheet any way>

Comment: @Stavros Jon  All the workbooks contain just tabular data, no charts or anything like that. The largest target worksheet has just over 700 rows of 10 columns. None of the worksheets has more than 10 columns of data. The purpose of the macro suite is to copy row contents from one sheet (in the target workbook) to another (in the output workbook) based workbook names, sheetnames and row numbers provided by the input workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent an hour or two working through the entire suite of macros, applying the technique suggested by @Fun Thomas, and tidying up some other loose code as I went along, I can no longer reproduce the failure on my most up-to-date version of the macros.

Thank you everybody for your thoughts and suggestions. I will now concentrate on offering further diagnostic data to my very original post about flickering grey screens when opening workbooks.